# innerHTML & accessing object property

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I want to get the value of the list id. Then access the object property.
For example, if egg is chosen:
I want to get egg.cost ( which is 9)

However, it is coming up as undefined.

HTML portion :

```
<select id = "list">
<option value = "egg">Eggs</option>
<option value ="banana">Banana</option>
</select>

</select>
<button onclick ="getSelectValue()"></button>
<div id ="example">testing</div>
```

javascript:

```
function getSelectValue(){
    var selectedValue = document.getElementById("list").value;
    document.getElementById("example").innerHTML=selectedValue["cost"];
}

var banana = {
              cost:1.39,
              servings:6,
              servingSize:1,
              costPerServing:.23
              };

var egg = {
            cost:9,
            servings:24,
            servingSize:1,
            costPerServing:.38

          };
```

Comment: So, the below answer by Ori Drori works if I use script text/javascript 
But is not working when put the javascript in a seperate file. I get the error code on  line "  var selectedValue = list.value;", which states : Cannot read property "value" of null"

Comment: The solution to this part of the issue was the fact that I had the script src to my js file in the header. When moved outside of that, at the end of the html content, it fixed it thanks to @Ori Drori

Answer (score 2):

Create a dictionary of objects(`items`), and get the relevant object using the value of the `<select>`:

```js
var list = document.getElementById("list");
var example = document.getElementById("example");
var items = {
  banana: {
    cost: 1.39,
    servings: 6,
    servingSize: 1,
    costPerServing: .23
  },

  egg: {
    cost: 9,
    servings: 24,
    servingSize: 1,
    costPerServing: .38

  }
};

function getSelectValue() {
  var selectedValue = list.value;
  example.innerHTML = items[selectedValue].cost;
}
```

```html
<select id="list">
<option value = "egg">Eggs</option>
<option value ="banana">Banana</option>
</select>

<button onclick="getSelectValue()">Get cost</button>
<div id="example">testing</div>
```

Comment: @OriDrori Thank You..this works with <script type="text/javascript"> inside the html file. However when i try to apply it using a seperate js file, the button does nothing, the error code in the console is for the var selectedValue = list.value;   .. it says Uncaught typeError: cannot read property 'value' of null

Comment: Move this two lines into your script file as well:
`var list = document.getElementById("list");
var example = document.getElementById("example");`

Comment: Yes, I copied exactly what is posted above. The Js file consist of : var list =  up to and including the function getSelectValue.  And the HTML , i linked my js file properly,( i tested it already with something basic).. is there another library i need to import  or something?

Comment: Nope. You're probably loading the JS file in the header. Move the script tag to the end of the body.

Comment: That worked !...geez I was tinkering on this for quite a while..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That’s because `selectedValue` is the string `"egg"`, not the variable `egg`. You’ll need to group both of your objects in another object (let’s call it `foods`), like so:

```
var foods = {
  egg: {
    // …
  },
  banana: {
    // …
  }
}
```

Then you can extract the values by `foods[selectedValue].cost`.